# How to center text in AutoCompleteTextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

is it possible to center text inside SimpleAutoCompleteTextField?

I have tried Directionaly but no 'center' there. Couldn't find align option also. Any suggestions?

```
SimpleAutoCompleteTextField(
              controller: widget._ingi_name_controller,
              key: searchIngredientKey,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:
                      BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
                hintText: 'hint',
              ),
              suggestions: widget.ingredientSuggestions,
              clearOnSubmit: false,
              textChanged: (text) {
                setState(() {});
              },
              submitOnSuggestionTap: true,
              textSubmitted: (text) {}),
```

Comment: Currently text alignment is not supported by the plugin you are using. There's an open issue for it : https://github.com/felixlucien/flutter-autocomplete-textfield/issues/67